# Unique Object Id's in DynamoDb?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I've been doing some research on DynamoDb and a common scenario I see is where a sort key is created in a form like ORDER#{orderId}. Such as the below image in the re:Invent 2019 talk about DyamodDb.

[image]

I have some confusion around this. Where would a "unique" order like this come from? Everything I read says you're not going to be able to efficiently check all Orders in the system to guarantee uniqueness of a new OrderId. In a real scenario would it be fine to just generate a UUID and use that here?

Comment: "you're not going to be able to efficiently check all Orders in the system to guarantee uniqueness of a new OrderId". Why?

Comment: Because that would presumably require you to do a scan of all order entries across all partitions, which is going to be a very expensive process